# Problems converting integrer to array using the modular arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays

So I want to convert this integrer **03600029145** into an array.

I've tried this:

```
int firstdigits;
int array[11];

cin >> firstdigits;

for (int i = 10; i>=0; i--)
{
    array[i] = (firstdigits % 10);
    firstdigits /= 10;
}
```

But the output says that array contains this: **0214748364** (from 10 to 0)

Reminder: I know that the integrer is stored from 10 to 0. And that the correct way is from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `int` to store the value but maximum value you can store in an `int` is `2147483647(2^31-1)`. You should consider using `long long` or `unsigned long long`.